# Force Inno Setup to store data in non-admin HKCU with PrivilegesRequired=admin

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I have a VBA add-in component that's being installed as part of an application that can only write to the HKCU area of the registry (`GetSetting` and `SaveSetting` functions are sandboxed in VBA).

But, the installer also needs to place files in the Windows system folder so it therefore requires admin privileges.

When the installer runs under a non-admin account, the user is requested to provide admin credentials and then the intended HKCU path is no longer valid, causing the installation to fail.

How can I write to an admin protected area of the file system AND write to the non-admin area of the Windows registry within a single Inno Setup Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `runasoriginaluser` flag in [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) or  [`ExecAsOriginalUser` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser).

But you would have to develop a separate application or a (PowerShell) script that adds the required keys to `HKCU`. Actually you can do this using another very simple InnoSetup installer.

Comment: That looks like just the ticket Martin - than you! Now to go work out what to put in each part of this new two-part Inno installer...

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to pass variables from Inno exe1 to Inno exe2?

Comment: You could write the variables to a temporary INI file and then read them from the second installer, which should then delete the INI file when finished.

Comment: @JamieG Well, that's for a different question. Anyway, there are many options. Depending on what kind of parameters? Do you want to forward InnoSetup parameters specified by user when running the first instance to the second? Or do you want to pass some kind of state/information collecting during a run of the first instance to the second?

Comment: Anyway to pass arguments, see parameter `Parameters` in [`Run` section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) or parameter `Params` for [`ExecAsOriginalUser`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser). To consume parameters, see `{param:ParamName|DefaultValue}` [constant](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts). In Pascal code, use `ExpandConstant`, `GetCmdTail`, `ParamCount`, `ParamStr`.

Comment: If you need more help, you really need to start a new question and provide more details about your use case.